# AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute 'PY3'

Tags: python, dill

This is the error I encountered when trying to apply to the dataset, is there any way to fix it?

```
   /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:2645:  FutureWarning: The `pad_to_max_length` argument is deprecated and will be removed in a future version, use `padding=True` or `padding='longest'` to pad to the longest sequence in the batch, or use `padding='max_length'` to pad to a max length. In this case, you    can give a specific length with `max_length` (e.g. `max_length=45`) or leave max_length     to None to pad to the maximal input size of the model (e.g. 512 for Bert).
    warnings.warn(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-14-197e6d91bdbc> in <cell line: 1>()
     ----> 1 train_ds=  train_dataset.map(encode)
      2 # valid_ds=  valid_dataset.map(encode)

     21 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py in _save_code(pickler, obj)
    393     co_firstlineno = 1 if obj.co_filename.startswith("<") or obj.co_name == "<lambda>" else      obj.co_firstlineno
    394     # The rest is the same as in the original dill implementation
    --> 395     if dill._dill.PY3:
    396         if hasattr(obj, "co_posonlyargcount"):
    397             args = (
    AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute 'PY3'
```

Any way to fix that error, I am running on the free Google Colab environment

Comment: `pip install --upgrade dill`

Comment: colab might not support, so use a product like `vs code`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me that `PY3` was removed from `dill._dill` in https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/pull/499, and thus if the code you are using requires `dill._dill.PY3`, you will need to install an older version of `dill` that has `PY3` defined.  So, not the current version of `dill`... so a release earlier than `dill-0.3.6`.

Comment: I tried the !pip uninstall dill command
!pip install dill==0.3.6 and it doesn't work, what should i do, I really don't have a fix

Comment: Not `dill-0.3.6` -- you need a version easier than that (e.g. `dill-0.3.5.1`)

Answer (score -1):

Three things to try immediately based on the error:

1. `pip install --upgrade dill`
2. make sure that you are using the correct version of python

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    # Python 3 specific code
```

3. uninstall and reinstall

```
pip uninstall dill
pip install dill
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, is there any other way